# Javascript for..in on object property

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"client_id":1},{"id":2,"client_id":1}]}
```

I'm trying to do a `for...in` but something is not going well.

Look at my code:

```
for (post in data) {
    console.log(post.client_id); //return undefined
}
```

But if I do this:

```
for (i=0 ; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].client_id); //return the correct value
}
```

Why can't I iterate with `for..in` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should NEVER iterate arrays with `for/in`.  That structure iterates properties of the object.  You will get all the array elements, but you may also get other iterable properties of the object too.

Arrays should always be iterated with a traditional `for` loop as in:

`for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`.

Second off, you have to make sure you're following your own data structure properly.  You have this:

```
var item = {"data":[{"id":1,"client_id":1},{"id":2,"client_id":1}]};
```

which spread out some more looks like this:

```
var item = {
    "data":[
        {"id":1,"client_id":1},
        {"id":2,"client_id":1}
     ]
};
```

So, your JSON is an object.  That object has one property in it called `data` and that one property's value is an array, which contains objects.  You would get the first item in the array with this:

```
item.data[0]
```

Or the properties on that object with this:

```
item.data[0].id
item.data[0].client_id
```

You would iterate all the items in that array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.data.length; i++) {
    // access each object in the array
    item.data[i].id
    item.data[i].client_id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of the "data" property is an array. You need:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; ++i)
  console.log(json.data[i].client_id);
```

That's assuming that the JSON has been parsed and stored in a variable called "json".  If it's actually called "data", then it'd be "data.data" instead of "json.data".

You really should not use `for ... in` loops for real arrays.  It's a bad habit for a variety of reasons.  Use a numeric index or something like the `.forEach()` facilities available in newer browsers.

Comment: +1 I also think in this example, for this reason, it's safer to stick with a good old `for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)`

Comment: it's a bad habit for what reason? Could you say some or suggest an article? Thankssss

Comment: Some libraries extend the Array prototype object, and your loop will stumble into random other properties you don't expect.  That's why `for ... in` is a bad idea.  For real numerically-index arrays, always use numeric index variables and plain old `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
for (var post in data) {
      console.log(data[post].client_id); //return undefined
}
```

this is the correct form to iterate using for... in

Answer (score 0):

```
for (post in data) {
    console.log(post.client_id); //return undefined
}
```

you're doing this wrong, try it like this:

```
for (post in data) {
    console.log(data[post].client_id); //return undefined
}
```

you should actually also include a filter, since stuff from the prototype can leak in:

```
for (post in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(post)) {
        console.log(data[post].client_id); //return undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the structure of your JSON. Notice that you've got an outer object with only a single top-level property: `data`.

```
{ "data":
    [
        {"id":1,"client_id":1},
        {"id":2,"client_id":1}
    ]
}
```

`data` doesn't have a `client_id` property: it's an array of the sub-entries that you're trying to iterate over, and *those* have `client_id` properties. This is why your loop that indexes `data` works.